# Manually update core from 7.0 to 7.78 in one fell swoop

Tags: 7

I have recently become an admin for a site that has not been updated since 2011. there are broken links (internal links to the site's blog go to page not found, index error.) I think this is due to a bug, so I want to update the software. However this would be a manual update of Drupal Core and I'm wary of doing anything that might mess up the site's code, not being a coder myself.

Should I go somewhere in the middle of the 7.x updates, or should I go straight to the latest one? What issues may arise from my site from updating to the most recent available?

Comment: Rebuild from scratch with D9

Answer (score 1):

The latest update contains all of the updates before so going straight to the latest one should be okay and is what is usually recommended. Be sure to backup your site and test the backup on a dev copy.

You should update your contributed modules at the same time as some of them may rely on updated versions of Drupal (core).

Lastly and very importantly, there have been numerous security releases since the 1st release and some of them are quite bad so I would say you should probably assume your site is compromised. That's 78(!) releases you've missed out on, including the infamous [*Drupalgeddon*](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-7600).